# analytic in open unit disk,corresponding to a bounded sequence and a bounded functional sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in open unit disk, we need to show there exist $\{z_n\}$ with $|z_n|<1$ and $|z_n|\rightarrow 1$ then $f(z_n)$ is bounded.

could any one give me Hints for this one?

Comment: What are your tools? Is it from a book or a homework?

Comment: "then" doesn't make sense there.  Do you mean "and"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If no such sequence exists, $f$ has only finitely many zeros in the open unit disk.  Use the Maximum Modulus principle on $p(z)/f(z)$ for a suitable polynomial $p$.

Comment: I do not understand the connection between non-existance of such sequence and finitely many $0$'s.

Comment: @miosaki: Try thinking about the contrapositive of the first sentence of this answer: If there are infinitely many zeros, then can you find such a sequence?

Comment: @JonasMeyer If there are infinitely many zeros of $f$ in the open unit disk then by the theorem "every bounded infinite set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}^n$"  and hence by Identity Theorem of analytic function we get  $f\equiv 0$ thats what I can say. But here limit point may not be in the open unit disk right? Then I can not say $f\equiv 0$

Comment: contrapositive statement of the 1st line of the answer: $f$ has infinitely many zeros $\rightarrow$ there exist such sequence. but still I do not get.

Comment: If there are infinitely many zeros, they have a limit point.  If that limit point is in the open disk, $f = 0$ everywhere.  Otherwise it's on the circle $|z|=1$, and you take $z_n$ to be a sequence of those zeros.