# Show existence of bounded sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been given the following statement which I need to prove and I think I've got good proper proof, except for one small step (*) which I have trouble formalizing.

The problem is as follows:

**Given $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the open unit disc and is nonzero there, show that there exists a sequence $|z_{n}|\rightarrow 1$ such that $|f(z_{n})|$ is bounded.**

My attempt:

Define $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ which is a holomorphic function on the open unit disc (since $f(z)$ is holomorphic and nonzero).

We assume by contradiction that for every sequence $|z_{n}|\rightarrow 1$ it follows that  $|f(z_{n})|$  is unbounded.
Then I want to say (*) if $|z_{n}|\rightarrow 1$ then $|f(z_{n})|\rightarrow \infty$ .

If that is correct then $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow 1}g(z)=0$. (**)

We can look at the compact set $|z|\leq r$ for $0<r<1$.

By the maximum modulus principle on $g(z)$ we have $\forall |z|\leq r \rightarrow  |g(z)|\leq max_{|z|=r}|g(z)|$.

Taking the limit $r\rightarrow 1^{-}$ and using (**) yields $\forall |z|<1 \rightarrow  |g(z)|\leq 0$.

Thus, $g(z)=0$ in the unit disc which contradicts $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$. QED.

Regarding the small step (*):

Unfortunately I do not think it is correct, as there are sequences which are unbounded but nonetheless, they do not approach infinity.
I do feel however this is the direction one needs to follow in order to tackle this problem.
I would like to hear your input regarding this proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192254/analytic-in-open-unit-disk-corresponding-to-a-bounded-sequence-and-a-bounded-fun

Comment: For $r = 1 - 1/n$ choose $|z_n|=r$ such that $|g(z)|\le |g(z_n)|$ for all $|z|\le r$.

Comment: If $f(z_n)$ would not converge to $\infty$, then it would have a bounded subsequence.

Comment: Thank you! That solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $b_n=|f(z_n)|$ of nonnegative numbers is unbounded, a *sub*sequence must approach infinity. Unbounded means you can find for each $k$  an element of the sequence $b_{i_k}>k$.  Choose them so that $i_k>i_{k-1}$, and there you've got your sequence going to infinity.