# Holomorphic function, existence of a sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D$. Prove that there exists a sequence $\lbrace z_n\rbrace$ such that $|z_n|\rightarrow 1$ and $\lbrace f(z_n)\rbrace$ is bounded.

Now, what I did is 
$f$ is analytic on $D$ and $|f(z)|<1$. Let $z_0,z_1,z_2,...$ be zeros on $D$ then each $|z_i|<1$ on $D$ and let $z_n$ be the zeros of $f$ and I am stuck. I know that I should put the zeros in a sequence form, any ideas?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192254/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has infinitely many zeros, you are done (because $f$ has only finitely many roots in any compact subset of $D$).

Else, you can can divide $f$ by a polynomial $g$ so that $f/g$ has no roots on $D$, and you can check that the problem is equivalent for $f$ and $f/g$.

Now, assume for the sake of contradiction that the statement doesn’t hold for $f/g$, it follows that $h=(f/g)^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $D$, without any roots, and such that $h$ goes to zero on the border of $D$. As a consequence, by the Cauchy formula, $h(0)=0$, a contradiction.